# SPComponentLoader.loadCss

Tags: spfx, spcontext

Can we use multiple time `SPComponentLoader.loadCss` like as below:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('...');
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('...');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. This blog post shows an example that does so.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-create-birthday-webpart-microsoft-teams-4-hours-neiy-darry/

[image]